# a virtual assistant in python with voice activation

Tags: python, speech-recognition

so I was making a virtual assistant in python in which the system gets activated when u call it by its name and then you can make it work according to what you say but it shows an error unindentation even though there isn't any here is the code where the error comes

```
ACTIVATE = False

engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(audio): #here audio is var which contain text
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wish():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("good morning, i am your virtual assistant")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("good afternoon, i am your virtual assistant")
    else:
        speak("hello, i am your virtual assistant")

def Command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        query1 = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')


        #return query1

if ACTIVATE == False:
    query1 = Command().lower()
    if "ACTIVATE" in query1:
        ACTIVATE = True
```

and it shows the error like

```
  File "C:\Users\Vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\New folder\VIRTUAL ASSISTANT ACTIVATION.py", line 47
    if ACTIVATE == False:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

in case there is a mistake in any other part of the code
here is the full code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import datetime
import pyttsx3
import webbrowser
import random
import os
import pyaudio

#text to speech

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)

#print(voices)
ACTIVATE = False

engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(audio): #here audio is var which contain text
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wish():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("good morning, i am your virtual assistant")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("good afternoon, i am your virtual assistant")
    else:
        speak("hello, i am your virtual assistant")

def Command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        query1 = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')


        #return query1

if ACTIVATE == False:
    query1 = Command().lower()
    if "ACTIVATE" in query1:
        ACTIVATE = True


if ACTIVATE == True:

    #now convert audio to text
    def takeCommand():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listening...")
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            print("recognizing...")
            speak("recognising")
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
            print(f"user said:{query}\n")

        except Exception:
            speak("i dont understand")
            print("i dont understand..")     #for error handling
            return "none"
        return query

    #for main function

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        wish()
        while True:
            query = takeCommand().lower()

            if "wikipedia" in query:
                speak("searching details...")
                query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 2)
                print(results)
                speak(results)

            elif "what's up" in query:
                stMsgs = ['asif now im only helping you with whatever you need me for', 'I am fine!, lets talk about you are you fine?', 'oh, nothing','i am okay ! How are you']
                ans_q = random.choice(stMsgs)
                speak(ans_q)  
                ans_take_from_user_how_are_you = takeCommand()

            elif "how are you" in query:
                stMsgs = ['i am fine, how about you!', 'I am fine!, lets talk about you are you fine?', 'I am nice and in full mood of helping you','i am okay ! How are you']
                ans_q = random.choice(stMsgs)
                speak(ans_q)  
                ans_take_from_user_how_are_you = takeCommand()

            elif "fine" in query or "im good" in query or "even im okay" in query or "nice" in query or "yeah" in query or "yes im nice" in query or "yes" in query:
                speak("oh that's nice, anyways what can i help you with today?")

            if "whats the weather " in query:
                speak("looking for the weather...")
                #r = sr.Recognizer()
                results =webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN911IN911&biw=1536&bih=763&sxsrf=ALeKk02WEeO5ibqsklVfK4AaRYshJYil7g%3A1598262964246&ei=tI5DX63LDrSX4-EP_bOA8A4&q=google+weather&oq=googweather&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB46BAgAEEdQ7i1Y0jJgwTxoAHACeAGAAYEDiAHmBZIBBzEuMi4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab")
            elif "hello" in query or "hi" in query or "hey" in query:
                stMsgs = ['hi how can i help you today', 'hello there, what can i do for you', 'hey, what can i help you with today','hello, what do you want me to do today']
                ans_q = random.choice(stMsgs)
                speak(ans_q)  
                ans_take_from_user_how_are_you = takeCommand()

            elif "what's the time" in query:
                speak("the time is")
                webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=time&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN911IN911&oq=time&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i61l2.584j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")

            elif "your name" in query or "who are you" in query:
                speak("my name is jarv")

            elif "who created you" in query or "how were u made" in query:
                speak("i am created by vatsal, and i owe a big thanx to him")

            elif "open amazon" in query:
                speak("opening amazon.com")
                webbrowser.open("https://www.amazon.in/")

            elif "open youtube" in query:
                speak("opening youtube")
                webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com")

            elif "open google" in query:
                speak("opening google")
                webbrowser.open("www.google.co.in")

            elif "open my channel" in query:
                speak("opening dietichen")
                webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/c/dietichen")

            elif "music from laptop" in query or "music" in query:
                speak("ok playing music")
                music_dir = "./music"
                musics = os.listdir(music_dir)
                os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, musics[0]))

            elif "video from laptop" in query or "play videos" in query:
                speak("ok playing music")
                video_dir = "./video"
                videos = os.listdir(video_dir)
                os.startfile(os.path.join(video_dir, videos[0]))

            elif "open my studio" in query or "youtube studio" in query:
                speak("opening youtube studio")
                webbrowser.open("https://studio.youtube.com/channel/UCNcVMyq5JyZ5V_TXN6KUgbA")


            elif "open my gmail" in query:
                speak("okay, opening your gmail")
                webbrowser.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")

            elif "open spotify" in query:
                speak("opening spotify")
                webbrowser.open("https://open.spotify.com/")

            elif "play dance monkey" in query:
                speak("okay, playing dance monkey from the artist tones and i")
                webbrowser.open("https://open.spotify.com/track/2XU0oxnq2qxCpomAAuJY8K?si=hqT3uLOtQnmV9glVfKP84g")

            elif "open my favourite songs album" in query:
                speak("opening your favourite music albumb")
                webbrowser.open("https://open.spotify.com/artist/2NjfBq1NflQcKSeiDooVjY?si=XvPrJaBNSnadmX8iWTlpyw")

            elif "open google classroom" in query:
                speak("opening google classroom")
                webbrowser.open("https://classroom.google.com/u/3/h")

            elif "goodbye" in query or "goodnight" in query or "shut up" in query or "bye" in query or "get lost" in query or "stop" in query:
                speak("good bye")
                quit()


            elif "shutdown" in query:
                speak("shutting down")
                os.system('shutdown -s')

            else:
                speak("sorry i dont understand")
```

please help me with this thankyou in advance

Comment: Its recommended you use a IDE like ``pycharm`` to format the code.

Comment: uh i use sublime text 3

Comment: mainly because you use ```try:``` without finishing the ```try... except``` syntax.  Python is expecting you to finish that.  Also, wrt editor, it's irrelevant to the issue.  Use whatever text editor you like.

Comment: oh yeah I wrote the code in that way but now the problem is the system doesn't listen to what you're saying to

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting an `except: pass` after the `try: query1 = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')`? It might need it and keep thinking you're inside the `try:` function.

Comment: oh ok thanx will try

Comment: oh so i just changed the code to the way u had told but now it cannot listen to what i say

Answer (score 0):

try this tested and working make sure all the python packages needed

```
import pyttsx3                                     
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import os
import sys
import datetime
import pywhatkit
import time
import pyaudio
import wikipedia

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id )
engine.setProperty('volume', 2.0)
engine.setProperty('rate', 160)



def fun_talk(query):
    engine.say(query)
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()


def get_audio():  #Take Command
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            print("Recognizing....")
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)

        except Exception as e:
            #print("Exception: " + str(e))
            pass
    return said.lower()



def wish_user():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        fun_talk("Good Morning")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        fun_talk("Good Afternoon")
    else:
        fun_talk("Good Evening")
    time.sleep(0)

# set the wake word
wake = "ava"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wish_user()
    while True:
        clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
        print("waiting for wake word...")
        
        query = get_audio()

                 # to listen for wake word
        if query.count(wake) > 0:
            print("is listening...")
            query = get_audio()
            

            if 'i am done' in query or 'go offline' in query:
                print("do you want me to shutdown?...")
                print("waiting for answer?...")
                fun_talk("do you want me to shutdown?")
                cmd = get_audio()
                if 'no' in cmd:
                    continue
                else:
                    fun_talk("commencing shutdown protocol. going offline")
                    fun_talk("goodbye for now")
                    sys.exit()



            
            elif'wikipedia' in query:
                fun_talk('Searching Wikipedia')
                query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=3)
                fun_talk("According to Wikipedia")
                print(results)
                fun_talk(results)
                clear()

                  #play any songs from youtube
            elif 'play' in query:
                song = query.replace('play', '')
                fun_talk(f'Playing {song} ')
                print(song)
                pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
                clear()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).